# Fixing number of decimals in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

here is my situation. I have created a DataSet, in my projet, that is linked to my Crystal report. Howhever, when I run the application and that I look at my report, there is decimal on all of my numeric fields. How can I remove them?

For your information, when I right-click on one of these numeric field, I don't have a format option (probably because it comes from a DataSet and not directly from the DB, I can't tell exactly).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't see the `Format Field...` option in the context menu? Is the field inside a text object? You can select the field inside the text object and get the Format Field option. Then you go to the number tab and use the Customize dialog to set the number of decimal places displayed.

Comment: No I don't see this field. It's not a text object actually. It's a field from the datatable that is from my dataset

Comment: also, you're right clicking the field after putting it on the report correct? because I can't think of any fields that don't have some kind of format option.

Comment: Most of them are String or Int64.
Yes. That's what I'm doing. On the "Field explorer" in the sidebar, I open the Database field, then the DataTable. I select the field I need and place them on the report and then I right click... And I don't see that "Format field" option...

Comment: Got it! Since the field types were "String" I couldn't format it as a number. Thanks for helping me out.